# Hard configuration Retrolambda

Tags: java, android, retrolambda

I'm trying to add library retrolambda to my project. On the official website we have short instruction which no works: add some plugins to build.gradle.

After that I got from AndroudStudio error:

```
One of the plugins you are using supports Java 8 language features. To try the support built into the Android plugin, remove the following from your build.gradle:
    apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
```

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }

        applicationId "com.example.house.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.0'
    }
}

// Required because retrolambda is on maven central
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application' //or apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
```

What can be wrong? What I should fix here ? I no found helps in internet.
Of course I can just remove this me.tatarka.retrolambda, but why ? We read on the official website this library "you have to add it" !